# Broken image icon when retrieving image inserted in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening everyone.

I have a website where a user is able to upload images and then display it with a "caption" after that.

I am able to insert the image into the database, along with the caption, however when I try to retrieve it, it displays as a broken image icon instead with the caption below it.

I will provide my code for inspection. Also if possible, I would like the image + caption to display one after another in  when I upload at different time. Hopefully someone is able to help me out. I'm quite the beginner so please put up with me!

**addexec.php** <-- an action

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
}else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $caption=$_POST['caption'];

        $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location, caption) VALUES ('$location','$caption')");
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();                 
     }
?>
```

Code in index.php that is used to retrieve the image:

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo '<div id="imagelist">';
    echo '<p><img src="'.($row['location']).'"></p>';
    echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
 ?>
```